# Can't push branch to github "Use git@github.com:Paratron/spacebattles.git"

Tags: macos, git, github, branch, push

I have a working branch in my Mac names database and I would like to push this branch to GitHub and have tried to do this by running:

```
git push -u origin database
```

And get the following error message:

```
You can't push to git://github.com/Paratron/spacebattles.git
Use git@github.com:Paratron/spacebattles.git
```

Are there known issues that could be the cause for this?
Are there any likely errors I could be doing that results in this error?

Comment: Can you post the contents of `.git/config` in the repository directory? It seems you have your remote incorrectly configured.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like it says, you can't push to `git://github.com/Paratron/spacebattles.git` (because it's a read-only URL).  Try this:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:Paratron/spacebattles.git
git push -u origin database
```

If you haven't ever used git in this way, you need to set it up to work with GitHub first: http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/

Also, are you Paratron?  If not, you'll need to fork his repository first: http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/.  Then you'll need to use your username instead (`git@github.com:YOUR_USERNAME/spacebattles.git`).

Answer (score 2):

The URL that you have set for the repository is a readonly URL.  You'll need to change the URL for the remote, using [`remote set-url`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote):

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:Paratron/spacebattles.git
```